# Namespacing and classes

Tags: python, class, module, scope

I'm trying to write some (in my opinion) readable code in Python. I need a module that will contain a number of classes. Theoretically I know everything that is needed to accomplish this: I can simply put class definitions in a single module file.

For readability purposes I want to put every class definition into separate file (they are starting to be quite lengthy!), and all these classes into one directory. Whenever I create new file  although it's contents are visible where I need them, class definition that's inside is scoped with unneeded module.

How should I do it? What is 'Python' way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import them all within `__init__.py`, and then have the consumer import the package.

```
from .module1 import Class1
from .module2 import Class2
 ...
```

Comment: What does preceding dot mean?

Comment: Sadly, I'm restricted to Python 2.4, as scripts will be run on third-party embedded device. This dot notation doesn't seem to work in legacy version. I have replaced it with full path to these sub-modules.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid hardcoding module paths, file, class, and function names in many places, you could do something like the following which dynamically imports (almost) all the Python files it finds in a package's subdirectory.

The key is remembering that the `__init__.py` file is a largely unconstrained Python script itself, and is therefore free to perform fairly sophisticated processing of its own to determine what's in the package's namespace.

File `package\__init__.py`:

```
def _import_package_files():
    """ Dynamically import all the Python modules in this module's sub directory. """
    import os
    import sys
    import traceback

    package_path = os.path.split(__file__)[0]
    package_directory = os.path.split(package_path)[1]

    for fn in os.listdir(package_directory):
        globals_, locals_ = globals(), locals()
        # process all python files in directory that don't start with underscore
        if fn[0] != '_' and fn.split('.')[-1] in ('py', 'pyw'):
            modulename = fn.split('.')[0] # filename without extension
            subpackage = ".".join([package_directory, modulename])
            try:
                module = __import__(subpackage, globals_, locals_, [modulename])
            except:
                traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
                raise # reraise exception

_import_package_files()
```

File `package\Class1.py`:

```
class Class1(object):
    pass
```

File `package\Class2.py`:

```
class Class2(object):
    pass
```

File `package\Class3.py`:

```
class Class3(object):
    pass
```

File `usepackage.py`:

```
import package

print(package.Class1)
print(package.Class2)
print(package.Class3)
```

Output from running `usepackage.py`:

```
<module 'package.Class1' from 'C:\Files\package\Class1.pyc'>
<module 'package.Class2' from 'C:\Files\package\Class2.pyc'>
<module 'package.Class3' from 'C:\Files\package\Class3.pyc'>
```

Comment: This is awesome. Works in python 3.4.1.