# best way to register all classes in a folder in python

Tags: python, import, module, frameworks

I am working as a summer intern at a fairly large company, me and another intern has been tasked with writing a background service from scratch in python(with given specifications). I can't say that I am a Python expert but I try to write as good code as possible and follow good practice. To the describe the service in a easy way it receives messages from a buss (amqp atm) and matches them against a patterns and preform actions depending on the pattern, all this is configurable from a json file.

To get down to the point, the service is suppose to be general and therefore a developer should be able to add different inputs and outputs classes. This is the structure I have right now.

- service.py
- input

  - __init__.py (Includes all .py files in the __all__ variable)
  - base.py
  - amqp.py

service.py

```
from input import *
import input
#use input.base.sources
```

input\base.py

```
sources = {}
def register_input(cls):
   sources[cls.input_name] = cls
   return cls

class InputBase(object):
    action(self, params):
...
```

input\amqp.py

```
@register_input
class AmqpInterface(InputBase):
    input_name = "amqp"
    action(self, params):
...
```

This works, but it doesn't look very nice and it also creates problems with include orders. Neither I nor the senior developer could think of a more pythonic way of solving this. 
Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem in a more elegant way?

Comment: Maybe try [codereview.se].

Comment: As I said, the senior developer working closes to me couldn't think of a better way at the moment, that's why I'm asking. I could ask some dev with python knowledge from another part of the company though.

Comment: It's another site, more suited to critiquing working code.

Comment: how are you able to call `action(self, params):` ? Is it just a placeholder?

Comment: You can add code to the `__init__.py` file to automatically import thes other modules and optionally their contents in the directory. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5135444/355230) and this [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14428820/355230) of mine.

Comment: @PeterWood Sorry, didn't realize that, will try it :)

Comment: @Pynchia I wrote down the code from memory so its just a placeholder

Comment: @martineau Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.