# Call from class in module without specifying its name

Tags: python, import

Can I import a class from a module, the same way as I can import the module like:

```
from module_name import *
```

so that I don't have to specify the "module.class" names every time I want a variable in it?

Example:
in module:

```
class SomeClass:
    var1 = "Hello"
    var2 = "Bye"
```

in main script:

```
def print_something(text):
    print(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_something(var1)        # "module_name.SomeClass.var1" should not be necessary, only "var1"
```

**Edit:**
What it does look like in the actual class, in the actual module:

```
class RGBcolors:
    # black-white-color
    bwc0 = (0, 0, 0)
    bwc1 = (1, 1, 1)
    bwc2 = (2, 2, 2)
    bwc3 = (3, 3, 3)
    bwc4 = (4, 4, 4)
    bwc5 = (5, 5, 5)
    bwc6 = (6, 6, 6)
    bwc7 = (7, 7, 7)
    bwc8 = (8, 8, 8)
    bwc9 = (9, 9, 9)
    bwc10 = (10, 10, 10)
    bwc11 = (11, 11, 11)
    bwc12 = (12, 12, 12)
    bwc13 = (13, 13, 13)
    bwc14 = (14, 14, 14)
    bwc15 = (15, 15, 15)
    bwc16 = (16, 16, 16)
    bwc17 = (17, 17, 17)
    bwc18 = (18, 18, 18)
    bwc19 = (19, 19, 19)
    bwc20 = (20, 20, 20)
    bwc21 = (21, 21, 21)
    bwc22 = (22, 22, 22)
    bwc23 = (23, 23, 23)
    bwc24 = (24, 24, 24)
    bwc25 = (25, 25, 25)
    bwc26 = (26, 26, 26)
    bwc27 = (27, 27, 27)
    bwc28 = (28, 28, 28)
    bwc29 = (29, 29, 29)
    bwc30 = (30, 30, 30)
    bwc31 = (31, 31, 31)
    bwc32 = (32, 32, 32)
    bwc33 = (33, 33, 33)
    bwc34 = (34, 34, 34)
    bwc35 = (35, 35, 35)
    bwc36 = (36, 36, 36)
    bwc37 = (37, 37, 37)
    bwc38 = (38, 38, 38)
    bwc39 = (39, 39, 39)
    bwc40 = (40, 40, 40)
    bwc41 = (41, 41, 41)
    bwc42 = (42, 42, 42)
    bwc43 = (43, 43, 43)
    bwc44 = (44, 44, 44)
    bwc45 = (45, 45, 45)
    bwc46 = (46, 46, 46)
    bwc47 = (47, 47, 47)
    bwc48 = (48, 48, 48)
    bwc49 = (49, 49, 49)
    bwc50 = (50, 50, 50)
    bwc51 = (51, 51, 51)
    bwc52 = (52, 52, 52)
    bwc53 = (53, 53, 53)
    bwc54 = (54, 54, 54)
    bwc55 = (55, 55, 55)
    bwc56 = (56, 56, 56)
    bwc57 = (57, 57, 57)
    bwc58 = (58, 58, 58)
    bwc59 = (59, 59, 59)
    bwc60 = (60, 60, 60)
    bwc61 = (61, 61, 61)
    bwc62 = (62, 62, 62)
    bwc63 = (63, 63, 63)
    bwc64 = (64, 64, 64)
    bwc65 = (65, 65, 65)
    bwc66 = (66, 66, 66)
    bwc67 = (67, 67, 67)
    bwc68 = (68, 68, 68)
    bwc69 = (69, 69, 69)
    bwc70 = (70, 70, 70)
    bwc71 = (71, 71, 71)
    bwc72 = (72, 72, 72)
    bwc73 = (73, 73, 73)
    bwc74 = (74, 74, 74)
    bwc75 = (75, 75, 75)
    bwc76 = (76, 76, 76)
    bwc77 = (77, 77, 77)
    bwc78 = (78, 78, 78)
    bwc79 = (79, 79, 79)
    bwc80 = (80, 80, 80)
    bwc81 = (81, 81, 81)
    bwc82 = (82, 82, 82)
    bwc83 = (83, 83, 83)
    bwc84 = (84, 84, 84)
    bwc85 = (85, 85, 85)
    bwc86 = (86, 86, 86)
    bwc87 = (87, 87, 87)
    bwc88 = (88, 88, 88)
    bwc89 = (89, 89, 89)
    bwc90 = (90, 90, 90)
    bwc91 = (91, 91, 91)
    bwc92 = (92, 92, 92)
    bwc93 = (93, 93, 93)
    bwc94 = (94, 94, 94)
    bwc95 = (95, 95, 95)
    bwc96 = (96, 96, 96)
    bwc97 = (97, 97, 97)
    bwc98 = (98, 98, 98)
    bwc99 = (99, 99, 99)
    bwc100 = (100, 100, 100)
    bwc101 = (101, 101, 101)
    bwc102 = (102, 102, 102)
    bwc103 = (103, 103, 103)
    bwc104 = (104, 104, 104)
    bwc105 = (105, 105, 105)
    bwc106 = (106, 106, 106)
    bwc107 = (107, 107, 107)
    bwc108 = (108, 108, 108)
    bwc109 = (109, 109, 109)
    bwc110 = (110, 110, 110)
    bwc111 = (111, 111, 111)
    bwc112 = (112, 112, 112)
    bwc113 = (113, 113, 113)
    bwc114 = (114, 114, 114)
    bwc115 = (115, 115, 115)
    bwc116 = (116, 116, 116)
    bwc117 = (117, 117, 117)
    bwc118 = (118, 118, 118)
    bwc119 = (119, 119, 119)
    bwc120 = (120, 120, 120)
    bwc121 = (121, 121, 121)
    bwc122 = (122, 122, 122)
    bwc123 = (123, 123, 123)
    bwc124 = (124, 124, 124)
    bwc125 = (125, 125, 125)
    bwc126 = (126, 126, 126)
    bwc127 = (127, 127, 127)
    bwc128 = (128, 128, 128)
    bwc129 = (129, 129, 129)
    bwc130 = (130, 130, 130)
    bwc131 = (131, 131, 131)
    bwc132 = (132, 132, 132)
    bwc133 = (133, 133, 133)
    bwc134 = (134, 134, 134)
    bwc135 = (135, 135, 135)
    bwc136 = (136, 136, 136)
    bwc137 = (137, 137, 137)
    bwc138 = (138, 138, 138)
    bwc139 = (139, 139, 139)
    bwc140 = (140, 140, 140)
    bwc141 = (141, 141, 141)
    bwc142 = (142, 142, 142)
    bwc143 = (143, 143, 143)
    bwc144 = (144, 144, 144)
    bwc145 = (145, 145, 145)
    bwc146 = (146, 146, 146)
    bwc147 = (147, 147, 147)
    bwc148 = (148, 148, 148)
    bwc149 = (149, 149, 149)
    bwc150 = (150, 150, 150)
    bwc151 = (151, 151, 151)
    bwc152 = (152, 152, 152)
    bwc153 = (153, 153, 153)
    bwc154 = (154, 154, 154)
    bwc155 = (155, 155, 155)
    bwc156 = (156, 156, 156)
    bwc157 = (157, 157, 157)
    bwc158 = (158, 158, 158)
    bwc159 = (159, 159, 159)
    bwc160 = (160, 160, 160)
    bwc161 = (161, 161, 161)
    bwc162 = (162, 162, 162)
    bwc163 = (163, 163, 163)
    bwc164 = (164, 164, 164)
    bwc165 = (165, 165, 165)
    bwc166 = (166, 166, 166)
    bwc167 = (167, 167, 167)
    bwc168 = (168, 168, 168)
    bwc169 = (169, 169, 169)
    bwc170 = (170, 170, 170)
    bwc171 = (171, 171, 171)
    bwc172 = (172, 172, 172)
    bwc173 = (173, 173, 173)
    bwc174 = (174, 174, 174)
    bwc175 = (175, 175, 175)
    bwc176 = (176, 176, 176)
    bwc177 = (177, 177, 177)
    bwc178 = (178, 178, 178)
    bwc179 = (179, 179, 179)
    bwc180 = (180, 180, 180)
    bwc181 = (181, 181, 181)
    bwc182 = (182, 182, 182)
    bwc183 = (183, 183, 183)
    bwc184 = (184, 184, 184)
    bwc185 = (185, 185, 185)
    bwc186 = (186, 186, 186)
    bwc187 = (187, 187, 187)
    bwc188 = (188, 188, 188)
    bwc189 = (189, 189, 189)
    bwc190 = (190, 190, 190)
    bwc191 = (191, 191, 191)
    bwc192 = (192, 192, 192)
    bwc193 = (193, 193, 193)
    bwc194 = (194, 194, 194)
    bwc195 = (195, 195, 195)
    bwc196 = (196, 196, 196)
    bwc197 = (197, 197, 197)
    bwc198 = (198, 198, 198)
    bwc199 = (199, 199, 199)
    bwc200 = (200, 200, 200)
    bwc201 = (201, 201, 201)
    bwc202 = (202, 202, 202)
    bwc203 = (203, 203, 203)
    bwc204 = (204, 204, 204)
    bwc205 = (205, 205, 205)
    bwc206 = (206, 206, 206)
    bwc207 = (207, 207, 207)
    bwc208 = (208, 208, 208)
    bwc209 = (209, 209, 209)
    bwc210 = (210, 210, 210)
    bwc211 = (211, 211, 211)
    bwc212 = (212, 212, 212)
    bwc213 = (213, 213, 213)
    bwc214 = (214, 214, 214)
    bwc215 = (215, 215, 215)
    bwc216 = (216, 216, 216)
    bwc217 = (217, 217, 217)
    bwc218 = (218, 218, 218)
    bwc219 = (219, 219, 219)
    bwc220 = (220, 220, 220)
    bwc221 = (221, 221, 221)
    bwc222 = (222, 222, 222)
    bwc223 = (223, 223, 223)
    bwc224 = (224, 224, 224)
    bwc225 = (225, 225, 225)
    bwc226 = (226, 226, 226)
    bwc227 = (227, 227, 227)
    bwc228 = (228, 228, 228)
    bwc229 = (229, 229, 229)
    bwc230 = (230, 230, 230)
    bwc231 = (231, 231, 231)
    bwc232 = (232, 232, 232)
    bwc233 = (233, 233, 233)
    bwc234 = (234, 234, 234)
    bwc235 = (235, 235, 235)
    bwc236 = (236, 236, 236)
    bwc237 = (237, 237, 237)
    bwc238 = (238, 238, 238)
    bwc239 = (239, 239, 239)
    bwc240 = (240, 240, 240)
    bwc241 = (241, 241, 241)
    bwc242 = (242, 242, 242)
    bwc243 = (243, 243, 243)
    bwc244 = (244, 244, 244)
    bwc245 = (245, 245, 245)
    bwc246 = (246, 246, 246)
    bwc247 = (247, 247, 247)
    bwc248 = (248, 248, 248)
    bwc249 = (249, 249, 249)
    bwc250 = (250, 250, 250)
    bwc251 = (251, 251, 251)
    bwc252 = (252, 252, 252)
    bwc253 = (253, 253, 253)
    bwc254 = (254, 254, 254)
    bwc255 = (255, 255, 255)

    black = (0, 0, 0)
    white = (255, 255, 255)

    red = (255, 0, 0)
    dark_red = (127, 0, 0)
    yellow = (0, 255, 0)
    blue = (0, 0, 255)
    red_orange = (255, 127, 80)
    green = (0, 255, 255)
    purple = (255, 0, 255)
```

Comment: You can avoid typing the module name with `from module_name import SomeClass`, but there is no way to avoid typing the class name. May I ask you why you want to do this?

Comment: Classes are logically different from modules (even though they have some similarities, like providing encapsulation). You cannot import from classes!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing classes from different files in a subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134893/importing-classes-from-different-files-in-a-subdirectory)

Comment: I think the best you can do is `from module_name import SomeClass` then `var1 = SomeClass.var1` But note that if the value of `SomeClass.var1` should ever change, you would still keep the old unchanged value.

Comment: [Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: Note that star imports inside a normal script are generally a bad idea. They flood the global namespace, which is messy and a recipe for name collisions.

Comment: I want to use variables inside the class, in the main script. I want to be able to use the variables in that class just as if they were global in a module, imported this way: "from module_name import *". The variable names won't "collide" with anything. It's the "color" module, from the other question you commented on, @farsil

Comment: It's not about importing scripts or classes from them, but a way to import a class just as importing a whole script with *, @WhatsThePoint

Comment: There is a way to copy class attributes into the global namespace, but it's really not a good idea, and people reading your code will hate you for doing that, and that includes yourself in six months time. ;) Besides, we don't normally use classes directly like that in Python. Instead, we create instances of the class.

Comment: FWIW, some languages have syntax that allows you to leave out the class name when referring to attributes, eg JavaScript's `with`, but experience shows that such "features" cause more headaches than they're worth.

Comment: I've updated my question with how it actually looks in the module. It won't be much of a problem. I may as well move everything else than bwc to another class. @PM2Ring

Comment: Keep data out of your variable names

Comment: What do you mean, @wim? Shouldn't I use numbers after letters in variable names? Why shouldn't I do so?

Comment: For example, it means you shouldn't use a sequence of variables named `bwc0-bwc255`, because a list called `bwc` with `len(bwc)==256` is better - you have to "level up" in the abstraction or the code will be very repetitive and ugly.

Comment: If you really want all those color names in your global namespace then don't put them in a class. Just define them at the module level and import them with a star import. But please consider a less messy approach, like a dictionary, and maybe a list for the grays.

Comment: BTW, you must have a funny monitor or something if you think  yellow = (0, 255, 0) and green = (0, 255, 255).

Comment: I copied some of the colors from a video. No, they were green and turquoise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use metaprogramming for this:

```
class GlobalNamespace(type):                                      
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        type.__init__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        globals().update({n: v for n, v in dct.items() if not n.startswith("__")})

class RGBcolors(metaclass=GlobalNamespace):
     ...
```

then, import module that contains RGBcolors

**NOTE:** please read the comments to your question and this answer, explaining why this is a bad idea in principle. Do not treat classes as modules. They are two different concepts.

Comment: This will overwrite existing values if there is a name collision.  Indiscriminately dumping a bunch of names into the global namespace is not a good use-case for a metaclass.

Comment: yes, but the question wasn't about is it a good idea or not. The question was: is it possible? It is possible regardless of how bad this idea is

Comment: I've added the warning message to the answer