# Get all functions of a module

Tags: python, module

A project has the following structure:

```
modulename
├── __init__.py
│
├── one
│   ├── function_1.py
│   ├── function2.py
│   └─── __init__.py
│
└── two
    ├── another_function.py
    ├── yet_another_function.py
    └─── __init__.py
```

Each `.py` (except the `__init__.py`'s which are empty) has content along the lines of:

```
def foo(x):
    return x

def bar(x):
    return x + 2
```

To use the module you import it it in the following way: `import modulename.one.function1.foo`. What I want to do is find all `.py` file names in the second to last place, for example `function1` or `another_function`.

The suggested solutions so far has unsuccessfully been:

- `dir(modulename.one)` which results in `['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`.
- `help(modulename.one)` which actually includes the function files' names under the title `PACKAGE CONTENTS`. How do I get a list of the `PACKAGE CONTENTS`?

EDIT: I could (as someone suggested) use `__all__` in the `__init__.py`'s, but I would prefer a simple built-in function or module.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `__all__` definition in your packages `__init__`files.

You can take a look at: http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html

which explains the `__all__` behavior in packages.

Comment: That seems like it would work, but as far as I understand you would have to write the `__all__` yourself? Or did I misunderstand? I would prefer if there was a way to find out programmatically.

Comment: Yes, you would have to write the `__all__` yourself. However, since `__init__.py` is a python module, it might be possible to populate it with code, using glob.glob and importlib.import_module.

Comment: That would be a possible solution (and if no better answer is posted I will do that). I will still wait for an eventual simpler solution.

Comment: You can write code to determine that contents of `__all__` at any time in your module (or a package's `__init__.py`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5135444/355230) of mine for an example.