# import class from different file in another folder not working

Tags: python

I already took a look at this solution [Importing classes from different files in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134893/importing-classes-from-different-files-in-a-subdirectory) , however it's still not working for me.

I have my `__init__.py` file where I make the import:

```
from api.get_channel_list import GetChannelList
```

but I get the following error when I try to run my app:

```
from api.get_channel_list.py import GetChannelList
ImportError: No module named get_channel_list.py
```

The directory is structured this way:

---

```
api
    --get_channel_list.py
static
templates
__init__.py
```

where api, static, and templates are folders. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I'm very new to python since like 2 days ago. Any pointers towards a solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention that, there's an __init__.py ont he api directory.

Comment: It should be `from api.get_channel_list import GetChannelList` don't need to put the `.py` part

Comment: if you put ```__init__.py``` on ```api``` directory, you should import it. And just mention, you can only do ```from api.get_channel_list import GetChannelLis``` on code file in the parent directory of ```api```

Comment: Which version of Python??  Try adding a dot  - `from .api.get_channel_list import GetChannelList `